# Where to put index-re-aliasing when re-indexing in the background?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I try to re-index an ES index with Java:

```
// reindex all documents from the old into the new index
QueryBuilder qb = QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery();
SearchResponse scrollResp = client.prepareSearch("my_index").setSearchType(SearchType.SCAN).setScroll(new TimeValue(600000)).setQuery(qb).setSize(100).execute().actionGet();
while (true) {
    scrollResp = client.prepareSearchScroll(scrollResp.getScrollId()).setScroll(new TimeValue(600000)).execute().actionGet();

    final int documentFoundCount = scrollResp.getHits().getHits().length;

    // Break condition: No hits are returned
    if (documentFoundCount == 0) {
        break;
    }

    // otherwise add all documents which are found (in this scroll-search) to a bulk operation for reindexing.
    logger.info("Found {} documents in the scroll search, re-indexing them via bulk now.", documentFoundCount);
    BulkRequestBuilder bulk = client.prepareBulk();
    for (SearchHit hit : scrollResp.getHits()) {
        bulk.add(new IndexRequest(newIndexName, hit.getType()).source(hit.getSource()));
    }

    bulk.execute(new ActionListener<BulkResponse>() {
        @Override public void onResponse(BulkResponse bulkItemResponses) {
            logger.info("Reindexed {} documents from '{}' to '{}'.", bulkItemResponses.getItems().length, currentIndexName, newIndexName);
        }

        @Override public void onFailure(Throwable e) {
            logger.error("Could not complete the index re-aliasing.", e);
        }
    });
}

// these following lines should only be executed if the re-indexing was successful for _all_ documents.
logger.info("Finished re-indexing all documents, now setting the aliases from the old to the new index.");
try {
    client.admin().indices().aliases(new IndicesAliasesRequest().removeAlias(currentIndexName, "my_index").addAlias("my_index", newIndexName)).get();
    // finally, delete the old index
    client.admin().indices().delete(new DeleteIndexRequest(currentIndexName)).actionGet();
} catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
    logger.error("Could not complete the index re-aliasing.", e);
}
```

In general, this works, but the approach has one problem:

If there is a failure during re-indexing, e.g. it takes too long and is stopped by some transaction watch (it runs during EJB startup), the alias is re-set and the old index is nevertheless removed.

How can I do that alias-re-setting if and only if all bulk requests were successful?

Answer (score 0):

You're not waiting until the bulk request finishes. If you call execute() without actionGet(), you end up running asynchronously. Which means you will start changing aliases and deleting indexes before the new index is completely built.

Also:

```
client.admin().indices().aliases(new IndicesAliasesRequest().removeAlias(currentIndexName, "my_index").addAlias("my_index", newIndexName)).get();
```

This should be ended with execute().actionGet() and not get(). that is probably why your alias is not getting set

Comment: I can only do `.actionGet()`, `.execute()` is no method in `IndicesAdminClient.java`. Nevertheless, I would somehow like to do that re-aliasing asynchronously but only after the re-indexing is done completely without errors. But I haven't found a way to do that yet.

Comment: use IndicesAliasesRequestBuilder instead of IndeicesAliasesRequest. Then you can call execute().actionGet(); If you want to make sure re-index succeeded completely without issue, you need to get the response. calling BulkRequestBuilder.execute().actionGet() returns a BulkResponse object. this object has a method called 'hasFailures()' as well as an iterator<BulkItemResponse>. Each BulkItemResponse has an 'isFailed()' method as well if you wnat to know which one failed.

Comment: Thanks, @coffeeaddict, but this only allows me to react to the execution of single bulks (e.g. after 50 re-indexed documents). But I would like to add a listener to the end/`.close()` of a BulkProcessor so that I can be sure that _all_ bulk requests have finished successfully. Or do I need some "error" flag?

Comment: ES doesn't work that way unfortunately (doesn't support transactions). ActionGet will ensure that ES has processed your request by forcing the call to be synchronous. You will have to manually iterate through all the response items to ensure they were all successful.

Comment: Thank you. I think I will have to re-formulate my question a bit after having experimented quite a lot. But what I still have a problem with is to scroll through scroll-search results asynchronously. But that should really go into a separate question, this one would get too complicated and confusing ... Thanks for the help, @coffeeaddict!

Comment: You can scroll through the results asynchronously. Just queue up the future that you get from 'execute()' and listen in on that queue in a different thread. Doing this will let your entire request run asynchronously. As long as you don't thrash ES with too many requests, the futures should all return back for analysis by your 'validation' thread.